# Unity Object Pooling With Scroll Rect To Achieve Endless Map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, infinite-scroll

As you can see in the video, I have a map with a `ScrollView` that I am instantiating in runtime. My problem is that I am trying to make an object pooling system so that when user scroll through the map it will be endless and keep going as long as they scroll.

I limited the movement only vertically and in the code I am putting all the objects in a list and for testing when I press "U" I am taking 10 object from bottom of the list and putting them on top of the list (Think it like when user is scrolling down, I'm taking the bottom objects and putting them on top to just make it endless).

But my problem is since I am using grid layout to layout the map prefabs, it is not making any difference from where in the list I take the objects and put them on top because grid layout system just repositioning them and all objects just seeing like they are still at their original positions.

What should I do to achieve my goal?

Video link: https://youtu.be/dwNwyK0ZGZc

```
#region Variables
[SerializeField]
private GameObject buildAreaPrefab;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject parentContent;
[SerializeField]
private GridLayoutGroup myGridLayout;

[SerializeField]
private int size = 10;
[SerializeField]
private int firstSize = 150;

public List<GameObject> poolList = new List<GameObject>();

private ScrollRect scrollRect;

private float lastValue = 0;
#endregion

private void Awake()
{
    scrollRect = GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
}

private void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < firstSize; i++)
    {
        GameObject newObj = Instantiate(buildAreaPrefab, parentContent.transform);
        newObj.name = newObj.name.Replace("(Clone)", i.ToString());
        poolList.Add(newObj);
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
    {
        //myGridLayout.startCorner = GridLayoutGroup.Corner.LowerLeft;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            poolList[i].transform.SetAsLastSibling();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            GameObject tempIndex2 = poolList[0];

            poolList.RemoveAt(0);
            poolList.Insert(poolList.Count, tempIndex2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add empty objects with proper size. e.g. if you took 10 objects out, add an object with 10x size

Comment: @Bijan Thanks for the idea, i will try and share the result.

Comment: @Bijan So it doesn't change anything because when i add an empty game object it is still beeing child of grid layout system and placing like other objects. Also i shouldn't add objects but instead use object pooling.

Comment: I thought it was a one-dimensional map like an endless sidescroller game. I don't think for a 2D map a scroll view would be a good idea. I think you need to implement your own logic for this scenario. but before keep looking into the possible ways of customizing scroll view

Comment: Yeah it is a bit though or i should say different for me. @Bijan